# Migration from Android v1 to V2

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

Hello everyone I am quite new to Flutter and I got stuck with this problem.

My app apparently is V2 but still, Android studio says that the app has to be migrated.

I did the steps that they suggested but still got the same result
Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong ?
This is the link with what I have to do:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

this is what I modified.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ipill">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.androidtutorialpoint.mymapsappsdirection.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:name="${ipill}"
        android:label="ipill"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"

                />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <!-- Specify that the launch screen should continue being displayed -->
            <!-- until Flutter renders its first frame. -->

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value=""/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the file MainActivity.kt contains the following

```
 package com.example.ipill

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

}
```

I tried also to use the flutter install --ignore-deprecation flag but they says that it is not working.

Any help because I got lost and I really need to make the app work, I found one similar question and I applied what they suggested but it did not work.

This is the log I get

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    D:\7_GitHub\Piller2.0\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:18:9-32 Error:
    Attribute application@name at AndroidManifest.xml:18:9-32 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <ipill> is provided.
D:\7_GitHub\Piller2.0\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: where are you getting that message? can you show your logs?

Comment: I just updated the post with the error.

Comment: there's no mention about that in the logs but it does show errors trying to get ${ipill}... where are you getting that variable from?

Comment: on github the link I just posted it says to use &{applicationName} so I did just that

Comment: the doc says "${applicationName}" and not "${ipill}"... you don't have to specify the actual name of your application, applicationName is an actual variable that will auto populate.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to solve this by setting `android:name` to

`android:name="${applicationName}"` in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

Apparently, even though you were already upgraded to V2 embedding, Flutter 2.10 has stricter checks than previous versions.

Comment: For who is in doubt which android:name, is the one in <application> tag inside <manifest>

Answer (score 6):

in your main/xml file, change `android:name` to `android:name="${applicationName}`

for official docs, you can refer to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects